# I would like to open a ticket on the robot-state-publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to open a ticket on the robot-state-publisher. But there is no link on the wiki page nor do I see how to do this in the github source page. Can someone please tell me how to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84551/i-would-like-to-open-a-ticket-on-the-robot-state-publisher/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Github show a link to issues at the top right.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-28**:
was not sure if issues was the place for tickets ie. report bugs.
thanks